# preg_match string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

how to find random number between of Parenthesis in jQuery

**jQuery:**

```
alert( preg_match("/^[0-9]$/", $('testSlide_1').html ) );
```

**HTML:**

`<div id='testSlide_1'>hard(1)</div>`

Could any one help plz

Comment: 1. `$('testSlide_1').html` -> `$('testSlide_1').html()`
2. Use `text()`

Comment: @bobthyasian not only that, but it should be `#testSlide_1`

Comment: Good catch, didn't even notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log($("#testSlide_1").text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]);
```